# RoR - Keep track of invalid ID 's in index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my `index()` method to let me know when an invalid ID has been passed in, but I don't want the page to barf with a 500.  I want (and have set up) the index method to skip model ID's it's unaware of - However, I want to keep track of those invalid model ID's somehow.

```
authorize :read
def index
  modelIds = []
  validIdList = ""
  models = ModelType.get_all_model_names()
  models.each do |model|
    id = ModelType.get_id(model)
    modelIds.push(id)
  end
  validIdList = modelIds.join(', ')
  @filter = "model_type_id IN (#{validIdList})"
end
```

How can I keep track of the invalid ID's that `index()` runs into?

Comment: hard to say how you should keep track of the ids without knowing your use case. But saving them to a file seems a reasonable enough approach.

Answer (score 1):

if you have standard resources `resources :something` then if you mean an invalid route like this

`/something/#{invalid_id}`

Then you will not catch these in the index action, they will be in the show action.  You could accomplish this in a `before_filter` in order to slightly reduce the amount of conditional logic in your show action.

In controller

`before_filter :check_valid_id, only: [:show]`

and in your private section of controller

`def check_valid_id
  unless find_something
    log(params[:id])
    redirect_to :index
  end
end`

You may also want to check_valid_id in other member routes such as edit, update, destroy and provide a flash message that the id was invalid

Comment: So there's no way to do something like: `invalidIds = "model_type_id NOT IN (#{validIdList})"`

Comment: You should not make a list of all the possible wrong ids. Your ID is a number up-to 2^64 ( or 1.84 x 10^19 ) minus the number of valid IDs. The computing required could render your site useless.

Comment: I may not understand what it is you are trying to do, it seems like you are mixing index/show responsibilities together.  Is this a search action?